# DllNotFound exception in unity3d

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, unity-game-engine, static-libraries

I try to use opencv in unity3d. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096329/opencv-unity3d-integration) advices some steps to integration unity+opencv. To do first step, I create a static library project on visual studio 2013. I add opencv library to this vs project.

I have installed `opencv2.4.10`, so I didn't install again `opencv`.
My steps are below :

```
1. Download OpenCV 2.4.10 

2. Create a Win32 console application - Select static library

3. Config opencv..
   3.1. Menu Project ---- $ProjectName Properties

   3.2. Choose Configuration Manager... and add x64 platform

   3.3. At configuration field, choose All configuration
         3.3.1. At Configuration Properties ---- C/C++ ---- Additional   Include Directories, add opencv include folders
     $opencv\build\include
     $opencv\build\opencv
     $opencv\build\opencv2 NOTE: $opencv is a folder that you have installed opencv

   3.3.2. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional Library         Directories, add opencv library folder
     $opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib

  3.4. At configuration field, choose Debug mode
       < <3.4.1. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional dependencies ---- add dependence libraries
      opencv_stitching248d.lib
      opencv_contrib248d.lib
      opencv_videostab248d.lib
      opencv_superres248d.lib
      opencv_nonfree248d.lib
      opencv_gpu248d.lib
      opencv_ocl248d.lib
      opencv_legacy248d.lib
      opencv_ts248d.lib
      opencv_calib3d248d.lib
      opencv_features2d248d.lib
      opencv_objdetect248d.lib
      opencv_highgui248d.lib
      opencv_video248d.lib
      opencv_photo248d.lib
      opencv_imgproc248d.lib
      opencv_flann248d.lib
      opencv_ml248d.lib
      opencv_core248d.lib
      NOTE: These file above are located at .\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib\

 3.5. At configuration field, choose Release mode
        3.5.1. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional dependencies ---- add dependence libraries
  opencv_***.lib

 NOTE: These file above are located at .\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib\

 3.6. Add $opencv\build\x64\v12\bin to System Environment Path
 3.7. Restart Visual studio
 3.8. Build project
```

Now I should do third step. But which files I should copy to  inside the `Asset > Plugins` folder? All project or a spesific file?

I put 2 files (that created using 64bit lib files) named `Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenCVStaticDll\x64\Debug\OpenCVStatic` (object file library) and `Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenCVStaticDll\OpenCVStaticDll\x64\Debug\OpenCVStatic` (precompiled header file)  inside the Asset > Plugins folder on `step 4`. I create them using 32bit same way, and put them under `C:/Program Fİles(x86)/Unity/Editor`.

I put all opencv_**.lib(under `x86/vc12/staticlib`) under `C:/Program Fİles(x86)/Unity/Editor`.

**Opencv-C++ Code :**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>    
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#pragma once
extern "C" {
    int func();
}


extern "C" {

int func()
{

    cv::Point p;
    p.x = 1;
    p.y = 0;
    return p.y;
}

}
```

**Unity C# code :**

```
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
                                        ITrackableEventHandler
{

[DllImport ("OpenCVStaticDll")]
private static extern int func();
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position.x + (int) (func ()*3),
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position.y,
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```