# how to detect human body in Unity3D

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I want to detect the whole human body in Unity3D is there any way to do that ? I think there is an easy way to do that in opencv. but I'am pretty new to Unity and I don't know how to use opencv in Unity3D. And can I use OpenCV in Unity3D?

Answer (score 1):

**I don't see an easier way to do that** if you are new(even if you are pro i think you would still use openCV)

**You can use openCv in unity**, there is an asset on asset store, it should be easy to implement and with any luck you will have an ready example for detecting a human body. Sorry to say that to you but the asset is paid.

Of course you can always integrate your openCv in Unity with your solution :)

Comment: oh I was hoping for a free asset but that's okay. And thank you very much for the reply^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the meaning  "I want to detect the whole human body in Unity3D" **But sure you can use openCV in unity** and you require to **write rapper** for it and fortunately there is a **paid package** available at assetstore.

1. [OpenCV for unity by Enox Software](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088)

If you have time and want to **avoid expensive plugin** then, you can write your own integration for unity using this

1. [Using OpenCV with unity blog](https://medium.com/@alanbuzdar/using-opencv-with-unity-f6507f34f033)
2. [OpenCV + Unity3D integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096329/opencv-unity3d-integration)
3. [OpenCV (EmguCV) integration in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612513/opencv-emgucv-wrapper-integration-in-unity?noredirect=1&lq=1)